# Look for a cell value (more than one instance) in a column then copy corresponding row values to another row (against other cell value)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to look for value of Forecast in cell (F column) (more than one instance - unique key is Prod and Cust), then copy corresponding row values to other rows identified by Edited Forecast value in another cell (more than one instance - unique key is Prod and Cust (same column).)

[image]

This is only copying Row values.

```vb
Private AutomationObject As Object

Sub Save ()
    Dim Worksheet as Worksheet

    Set Worksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet")
    Worksheet.Range("M18:AX18").Value = Worksheet.Range("M15:AX15").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a code writing service, it is necessary that you make an attempt first, include your question with the code attempt and explain what is not working with your code. If you have already made an attempt then please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: I am new to VBA

Comment: Private AutomationObject As Object

Sub Save ()

Dim Worksheet as Worksheet

Set Worksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet")

Worksheet.Range("M18:AX18").Value = Worksheet.Range("M15:AX15").Value

End Sub

===========
It is not correct, I am only copying Row values.
---------------------
Requirement is to Look for value of Forecast in cell (F column) (more than one instance - unique key is Prod and Cust), 
and copy corresponding row values to other rows identified by Edited Forecast value in 
another cell (more than one instance - unique key is Prod and Cust (same column).

Comment: Please do not post code in comment, you can edit your question and include your code there.

Comment: Check for top 3 or top 5 on here - have a function based answer that may help you.

Comment: Do these explanations mean that e.g. you want to write the values `30, 45, 20` to columns `I:K` of each row that has `1` and `2` in columns `D:E`?

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008 Yes I need the value 30, 45, 20 against Forecast value for Prod 1, Cust 2 to be copied to the columns I:K against Edited Forecast for Prod 1, Cust 2. ####### Prod 1, Cust 2 are unique values. It is having one row each for Forecast and Edited Forecast Value in excel. Edited Forecast is blank, need to copy Forecast to Edited Forecast. ##### Similarly there are other Prod, Cust combination, also have to copy those likewise.

Comment: And do you need to make it a VBA macro? Because easy solution would be just to concatenate columns D, E, F on Forecast and Edited Forecast sheets and then just use Vlookup/Xlookup to get the values

Answer (score 1):

### Fill Blanks (Unique Dictionary)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FillBlanks()
    
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "D3"
    Const sDelimiter As String = "@"
    Const dCols As String = "I:K"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    With ws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount, 2)
    End With
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(dCols)
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = drg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sString As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sString = sData(r, 1) & sDelimiter & sData(r, 2)
        If Application.CountBlank(drg.Rows(r)) = dcCount Then
            If dict.Exists(sString) Then
                If IsArray(dict(sString)) Then
                    drg.Rows(r).Value = dict(sString)
                Else
                    dict(sString).Add drg.Rows(r)
                End If
            Else
                Set dict(sString) = New Collection
                dict(sString).Add drg.Rows(r)
            End If
        Else
            If dict.Exists(sString) Then
                If IsArray(dict(sString)) Then
                    'drg.Rows(r).Value = dict(sString) ' overwrite!?
                Else
                    For Each rg In dict(sString)
                        rg.Value = drg.Rows(r).Value
                    Next rg
                    dict(sString) = drg.Rows(r).Value
                End If
            Else
                dict(sString) = drg.Rows(r).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    MsgBox "Data updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```